# Emacs on-the-fly mode changing

Tags: emacs

When writing shell scripts (which to my knowledge usually don't have .* suffix), I usually do something like the following

1) emacs foo
2) Type in #!/bin/sh
3) Close and reopen emacs so that the shell-script major mode is enabled

Is there any nice way so that I don't have to do step (3)? I could bind M-x shell-script-mode to some key combination, but is there some general way to make emacs re-evaluate the mode using its standard set of rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general way to do it would be <kbd>M-x normal-mode</kbd>

Comment: I have `(defalias 'nm 'normal-mode)` in my `.emacs` to make this a bit quicker to type.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (if (not (executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p))
         (normal-mode))))
```

The first bit `executable-make-buffer-file-executable-if-script-p` was not part of your question but is also useful: it makes the file executable if it wasn't already (if it looks like a script). If we end up flipping the execut bit, then we also set the mode.